# __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__ is not defined

Tags: android, jquery, webpack

I am developing a web app that uses jQuery (current version 3.3.1)

When I run the app on an Android stick, I get the following JavaScript error:

```
webpack:///./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js?:10325 
Uncaught ReferenceError: __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__ is not defined
```

Needless to say that my code works flawlessly when running on modern browsers. I am assuming the browser on the Android stick is not very modern that thus lacks some support.

Did anyone run into this problem in the past and know how to fix it?
I did some research and notice that many people are complaining about this issue, but nobody offered a solution.

Thanks

Comment: I found an answer on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52419733/webpack-amd-define-array-is-not-defined If your current proj is compatible with jQuery@2.2.4, you can downgrade. That did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve the problem, I had to run the following:

```
webpack --mode production
```

instead of transpiling it in development mode.